# Difference between Activity.class and Class class

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I was creating notification `Intent` that opens one of two activities depending on condition. Worked as expected since I have all intent flags required for this.

I tried to optimize my method flow by extracting new `Intent` and `Class`, so optimized code looked like this:

```
Class ActivityClass;

if (siteId > 0) {
   //...
   ActivityClass = DetailActivity.class;
} else {
   //...
   ActivityClass = MainActivityWithMenu.class;
}

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(appContext, ActivityClass);
```

But then my notification stopped opening activities, so I changed it to:

```
Intent notificationIntent = null;

if (siteId > 0) {
    notificationIntent = new Intent(appContext, DetailActivity.class);
} else {
    notificationIntent = new Intent(appContext, MainActivityWithMenu.class);
}
```

Second version works without any problems, but I was wondering what is the difference between `Activity.class` and `Class` class and why first snippet won't work with `Intent`?

**Whole function:**

```
String title = "Upcoming site:";


    Intent notificationIntent = null;

    if (siteId > 0) {
        pref.setNewVar("notificationSiteId", String.valueOf(siteId));
        notificationIntent = new Intent(appContext, DetailActivity.class);
    } else {
        notificationIntent = new Intent(appContext, MainActivityWithMenu.class);
    }


    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("siteId", siteId);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(appContext, 0,
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    Notification.Builder nBuilder = new Notification.Builder(appContext)
            .setContentTitle("Neeco - " + title)
            .setContentText(text)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.clock_start)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    boolean updateNotification = true;
    if (pref.getVar("notificationText") != null && !pref.getVar("notificationText").equals(text)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "New text in notification - " + text);
        nBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);
        nBuilder.setPriority(priority);
        pref.setNewVar("notificationText", text);
    } else if (pref.getVar("notificationText") == null) {
        nBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);
        nBuilder.setPriority(priority);
        pref.setNewVar("notificationText", text);
    } else {
        updateNotification = false;
    }

    if (updateNotification) {
        Notification notification = nBuilder.build();
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) appContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(Config.NOTIFICATION_ID.FOREGROUND_SERVICE, notification);
    }
```

Comment: For one thing, `class` is a mistake. It should be `Class<?>`. For another, you're using different classes in your snippets. One is `MainActivity.class`, the other is `MainActivityWithMenu.class`.

Comment: oh yeah, sorry about main activity, wrote first snippet here since it's already edited in code.

Comment: Then as far as I can tell, they're the same. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @shmosel I added my method to the question.

Comment: I tried your code and it is working- are you sure you are not changing something in the `if` so the updateNotification is false and you do not update the nottification at all?

Comment: @X3Btel This version is working, indeed, you need to replace condition with first snippet to get unclickable notification. As for updatenotification, it doesn't really matter since only one of two snippets is working properly.

Comment: @VladimirLitovkin yea i used this code with the first snipper: `if (condigion) {
            ActivityClass = MainActivity.class;
        } else {
            ActivityClass = Main2Activity.class;
        }`

Comment: @X3Btel I guess you're right since second snippet stopped working correctly... Will search for error elsewhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Class`

It's a compiled form of.Java file.
A class is a combination of methods, variables and data types. Every Java or Android project must have at least one class.
Android finally used this .class files to produce an executable Apk

Example:

```
public class Data{
    int ID;
    String Name;
    public void First_Method()
    {

    }
}
```

`Activity`

An activity is the equivalent of a Frame/Window in GUI toolkits. 
If we want to use an activity class, we must use extend Activity in your android project.

Example

```
public class Main_Activity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh, ok, in this case, is my #2 snippet correct? Or should I replace new Intent lines with something like Activity activity = DetailActivity? I tried that and I obviously can't create this type of object.

Comment: @VladimirLitovkin there is no reason your first condition to not work. Follow the guidelines shmosel gave you and post your code

Comment: @X3Btel since there's literally nothing special after this condition I posted whole method.